# Is there such thing as supreme board for international arbitrators?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, civil-engineering, international

My cousin is a mechanical engineer, got contacted today from someone who claimed to be working for the supreme board for international arbitrators ([sbia](http://sbia.org.uk)) and [ICAC](http://www.icac-lebanon.com/lb/) in the Middle East and north Africa region.

She told him he would have to pay $300 in order to get a 1 day course, or workshop, afterwords he would become an international arbitrator for engineering issues related to his field. Full sized images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa3JJ.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atM1d.jpg)

[image]

[image]

My cousin and I think this is a scam, and their website is bad and there's no mention about SBIA anywhere, no results on google, no social media presence. I would like to ask you about it though, have you ever heard about it? Is this a scam?

**Edit**

I think they are copycatting this http://www.incodir.org/, not only that, I hope you could read arabic, on the first image, it says in parentheses

[ريم الفانك](https://people.bayt.com/reem-alfanek/?lang=ar)

which also works in the organization I mentioned, I'm going to try to contact her somehow, either she's being impersonated in which case I'll see if we can press charges, otherwise she's part of the scam, I hope not.

**Edit 2**

I tried contacting president@incodir.org, the email didn't get delivered to report the case, well then I must conclude that they too are a part of the scam sadly, the rabbit hole goes deep.

Comment: They may well have an office in Ashford, but I would not spend any money in their direction...

Comment: Comment under a recent question on money.SE: "Can we add a bot that answers 'Yes, it's a scam' to every question that asks 'Is this a scam?'"

Comment: Why do you think these are two different organizations, and one is copycatting  the other? A single bunch of scammers might have 20 or 2,000 similar sites that you haven't found yet. But their choice of ICAC as an acronym is a bit ironic - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_Commission_Against_Corruption

Comment: Here's a third one - also with fractured English and speeling missteaks: http://www.equitycollege.org/about.html - they have a representative in " Austuralia", apparently ;)

Comment: @alephzero This is so sad, isn't there legal actions one could take against scammers? Regardless of my country, because my country is weak, isn't there someone to report to?

Comment: They don't seem to be doing anything illegal. "Separating fools from their money" isn't a crime in most countries.

Comment: "I tried contacting president@incodir.org" That was a bad move. They now have your email address. Expect lots of spam from "other organizations" trying to sell you stuff!

Comment: @alephzero ayyyyy yayyy yayy that's true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can't even write English on their certificate.

> ... training of good stand, and is in accord with American and
>   European standers...

That's an obvious typo. Of course it should say

> ... training of good sit, and is in accord with American and
>   European sitters...

Is it worth paying $300 for a joke certificate? That depends on the buyer's sense of humour, I suppose.